# Optional prompts in org-capture template using helm?

Tags: org-mode, helm, org-capture

Is there a way to bypass a prompt (set the value to nil) in an org-capture template with helm?

Specifically, template looks like this:

```
("m" "Meeting notes" entry (file "~/Dropbox/org/meetings.org")
       "* %^{Meeting Time}T %^{Title} %^g \n** %i%?\n " :prepend t)
```

How can I leave out the title (`%^{Title}`) or tags (`%^g`)? I've tried an empty string, but that aborts the capture. Pressing `enter` without any input selects the first helm completion.

Comment: In helm's mode-line, you should be able to see `C/M-RET:Empty`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`C-ENTER` seems to work for me when in the template substitution helm, which helm binds to `helm-cr-empty-string` in the helm interface.

(There's probably a better way of discovering this, but I just did it via trial and error having tried various other unsuccessful things such as `C-u ENTER`, `M-ENTER` and a simple `.`.)

Comment: For me it was actually `M-RET` that worked (on a mac with spacemacs), though I couldn't confirm what function it's bound to. How did you discover helm was binding to `helm-cr-empty-string`? When I run `describe-function` (spacemacs `SPC h d f`) it doesn't show any bindings : \

Comment: Glad that's helped. I think it'll be in the mode-specific bindings, so it'll only be bound when the helm interface is actually showing. I can see that binding with `C-h k C-ENTER` when the helm interface is popped up (`describe-key`).